ThreadPoolExecutor: Pick tasks from queue instead of executing the newly submitted task when queue is full
As per my understanding,
In ThreadPoolExecutor in Java, if a fixed bounded queue is provided, when tasks are submitted to it after corePoolSize threads are busy, they are added to the queue.
If however, the tasks are submitted when core threads are busy, and queue has reached its capacity, then in case a maximumPoolSize greater than corePoolSize is configured, the new tasks are executed in new threads, reaching up to maximumPoolSize.
This imo, is a little counter intuitive, as i would like the tasks submitted first to get executed. In case the tasks keep getting coming in at a pace similar to the execution of maximumPoolSize threads, the tasks in the queue will stay there forever and will never get picked.
If my understanding is not wrong, is there a way for the executor to pick tasks from queue and add the newly submitted task to it, instead of executing it.
I am using the below code to test
package com.multithreading;

import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class ExecutorOrder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2);
        ExecutorService e = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 4, 5,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,blockingQueue );
        Function<Integer, Runnable> threadGenerator = (Integer t) -> () -> {
            System.out.println("This is task " + t + ", now sleeping for 2 seconds: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
            System.out.println("Task " + t + " exits, " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        };
        e.submit(threadGenerator.apply(1));
        e.submit(threadGenerator.apply(2));
        e.submit(threadGenerator.apply(3));
        e.submit(threadGenerator.apply(4));
        e.submit(threadGenerator.apply(5));
        e.submit(threadGenerator.apply(6));
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        e.shutdown();
        //System.out.println(e.awaitTermination(7,TimeUnit.SECONDS));


    }

}


I have created a threadpool with 2 core threads, 4 max threads and queue of length 2.
I am submitting numbered tasks which sleep for 2 seconds and finish execution.

Tasks 3 and 4 are submitted before tasks 5 and 6.
Since Tasks 1 and 2 occupy corePoolSize threads, 3 and 4 are queued, and the queue reaches capacity.
When tasks 5 and 6 are submitted, number of threads get increased to  maximumPoolSize, and tasks 5 and 6 are executed in them, and not 3 and 4, queued before them.

Sample output:
This is task 1, now sleeping for 2 seconds: pool-1-thread-1
This is task 6, now sleeping for 2 seconds: pool-1-thread-4
This is task 5, now sleeping for 2 seconds: pool-1-thread-3
This is task 2, now sleeping for 2 seconds: pool-1-thread-2
Task 5 exits, pool-1-thread-3
Task 1 exits, pool-1-thread-1
Task 2 exits, pool-1-thread-2
Task 6 exits, pool-1-thread-4
This is task 3, now sleeping for 2 seconds: pool-1-thread-2
This is task 4, now sleeping for 2 seconds: pool-1-thread-4
Task 4 exits, pool-1-thread-4
Task 3 exits, pool-1-thread-2


This is a very good observation! Applause for this one. I'm not aware of way to achieve what you're looking for except maybe if you extend ThreadPoolExecutor and override execute(Runnable). But this one is tricky.

do you mean ...   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor  getQueue()   and   java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue

Is it not possible to implement a java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler that retrieves the queue from the executor and retrieves an old an  adds the new task to the queue? The executor is available to the rejected execution handler.

Do you need an atomic offer and poll for the task queue?

@SpaceTrucker the task is not getting rejected. If the queue is full, and maximumPoolSize has not been reached, the new task will be straightaway executed in a new thread. I want to know if instead the new task gets inserted into the queue, and the task to be executed picked from it

I'm not convinced that the tasks in the queue will stay there forever. Won't the threads above corePoolSize also start working on queued tasks once they have finished their task which was submitted to them when spawned?

Yes queue tasks will start getting executed whenever idle threads are present. But just for example if the pace of tasks getting submitted is same as of them getting executed, wouldn't the queue tasks remain untouched.

I believe  by looking at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Worker) that this will only happen for maxPoolSize - corePoolSize tasks since then all threads are spawned and if the queue remains full additional tasks will be rejected. Depending on how large the difference between core and max pool size is this could still be a considerable amount of time.
